# Trouble while compiling the next code in haskell (splicing in template haskell)

Tags: templates, haskell

I am getting this problem that happens while using inside a splice a variable/function that is not yet defined at compile time when checking the splice.
But I would like to ask if there is any way to do it so I can get the same result. The code is this one:

```
passFun :: Name -> Int -> [a] -> ([a],[b])
passFun f_name n list = (list, (passFunAux f_name n list))

passFunAux :: Name -> Int -> [a] -> [b]
passFunAux _ _ [] = []
passFunAux f_name n (t:ts)= y:(passFunAux f_name n ts)
     where y = testP f_name n t

testP :: Name -> Int -> a -> b
testP f_name n t = []
testP f_name n t = $(lamE (tupleParam (listVar n)) (body f_name (listVar n))) t
```

The code is supposed to get as input the name of the function, its number of input parameters and a list of tuples of n components each. Then this function calculates the output of the function for each of those tuples of inputs and returns a list of all the outputs.

```
GHC stage restriction:
      `n' is used in a top-level splice or annotation,
      and must be imported, not defined locally
    In the splice:
      $(lamE (tupleParam (listVar n)) (body f_name (listVar n)))
```